# C# Subscribe to event of a COM object with System.Reflection

Tags: c#, com, runtime, system.reflection

I have to following code that is working without System.Reflection:

```
Using COMlib;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
          private static void kxc_operationComplete(object result)
          {

          }

          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
               COMclass kxc = new COMclass();
               kxc.Init();
               kxc.OperationComplete += kxc_operationComplete;
               kxc.Operate();
          }
    }

}
```

I'm interested to obtain the result of the OperationComplete event.
How can be achieved with System.Reflection???

Until now I have this code:

```
//getting active x type
var COMtype = Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(Guid.Parse(CLSID.objcode), true);
//create object
object COMobj = Activator.CreateInstance(COMtype);
//call init method
COMtype.InvokeMember(“Init”, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, COMobj, null);


//query for event
EventInfo ei = COMtype.GetEvent(“OperationComplete”);  //the eventinfo is null
//bind to my class method
MethodInfo method = Type.GetType("test.Program").GetMethod("kxc_operationComplete");
Delegate handler = Delegate.CreateDelegate(eventInfo.EventHandlerType, kxc, method);
//but is not working
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

**UPDATE1:** I got a suggestion that I shoud use [ComEventsHelper](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Runtime/InteropServices/ComEventsHelper.cs) class, but I don't know how can it be inserted into my code.

Comment: What does Type.GetEvents return?

Comment: Type.GetEvents returns an empty array, also Tyep.GetMethods returns a list of methods that doesn't contain Init and Operate methods, but I'm able to invoke them. I think is related to the late binding of a COM object.

Comment: How about changing "OperationComplete" to "operationComplete"(case sensitive)?

Comment: No luck, because OperationComplete is the event name.

Comment: Seems to be a @jon-skeet question

Comment: These [AddEventHandler using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121441/addeventhandler-using-reflection), [c# Adding a listener to Event with only the method name (text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49290793/c-sharp-adding-a-listener-to-event-with-only-the-method-name-text) may be helpful. From that, how about trying COMobj.GetType().GetEvent() instead of COMtype.GetEvent()?

Comment: I've tried first link. Actually my code adapts the link code. COMobj.GetType().GetEvent() is equal with COMtype.GetEvent(). I've tried both ways. Thanks.